# Neural network for univariate regression with numpy gives only linear results

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, regression, non-linear-regression

My goal is to create a neural network with a single hidden layer (with ReLU activation) that is able to approximate a simple univariate square root function.
I have implemented the network with numpy, also did a gradient check, everything seems to be fine, except for the result: for some reason I can only obtain linear approximations, like this: [noisy sqrt approx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWa7c.png)

Tried changing the hyperparameters, without any success.  Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np

step_size = 1e-6
input_size, output_size = 1, 1
h_size = 10
train_size = 500
x_train = np.abs(np.random.randn(train_size, 1) * 1000)
y_train = np.sqrt(x_train) + np.random.randn(train_size, 1) * 0.5

#initialize weights and biases
Wxh = np.random.randn(input_size, h_size) * 0.01
bh = np.zeros((1, h_size))
Why = np.random.randn(h_size, output_size) * 0.01
by = np.zeros((1, output_size))

for i in range(300000):
    #forward pass
    h = np.maximum(0, np.dot(x_train, Wxh) + bh1)
    y_est = np.dot(h, Why) + by

    loss = np.sum((y_est - y_train)**2) / train_size
    dy = 2 * (y_est - y_train) / train_size

    print("loss: ",loss)

    #backprop at output
    dWhy = np.dot(h.T, dy)
    dby = np.sum(dy, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    dh = np.dot(dy, Why.T)

    #backprop ReLU non-linearity    
    dh[h <= 0] = 0

    #backprop Wxh, and bh
    dWxh = np.dot(x_train.T, dh)
    dbh = np.sum(dh1, axis=0, keepdims=True)

    Wxh += -step_size * dWxh
    bh += -step_size * dbh
    Why += -step_size * dWhy
    by += -step_size * dby
```

Edit:
It seems the problem was the lack of normalization and the data being non-zero centered. After applying these transformation on the training the data, I have managed to obtain the following result: [noisy sqrt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw8W8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get your code to produce a sort of piecewise linear approximation:

[image: Piecewise linear approximation to $y=\sqrt(x)$]

if I zero-centre and normalise your input and output ranges:

```
# normalise range and domain
x_train -= x_train.mean()
x_train /= x_train.std()
y_train -= y_train.mean()
y_train /= y_train.std()
```

Plot is produced like so:

```
x = np.linspace(x_train.min(),x_train.max(),3000)
y = np.dot(np.maximum(0, np.dot(x[:,None], Wxh) + bh), Why) + by
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Included the normalization, and it works pretty well now indeed, thanks. Can you give some intuition why it is so crucial to have our dataset normalized and zero-centered?

Comment: My guess is your ReLUs are getting stuck on or off for your entire dataset.  If the hidden activations are always the same, regardless of the input pattern, the output is going to be a linear function.  By making sure some of your inputs are negative, I guess you're more likely to have some hidden units on and some off, so that different sets of hidden units can learn different parts of the sqrt function.